# PHP : Error While Using String Separator inside a Class

Tags: php, class, variables, object, separator

Why I can't use separators (.) in variables inside a class?

```
class Object(){
    public $var  = "Hello"."World";
    # Or
    public $test = "Hello";
    public $var2 = $this->test."World";
}
```

This code gives me this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in test.php on line 2

And how should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you cannot declare class properties with variable expressions. That means you cannot use any arithmetic operators `+ - * /` or the concatenation operator `.`, and you can't call functions. Out of your three lines, only `$test` should work; the other two will give you errors.

If you need to build your strings dynamically, do it in the constructor.

```
class Object {
    public $test = "Hello";
    public $var2;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->var2 = $this->test . "World";
    }
}
```

By the way, `.` is not a "string separator". It's the concatenation operator. You use it to *join* strings, not *separate* them.